# Facebook Thrift SSH Frame Size Error

Tags: python, facebook, ssh, thrift

I am running the Facebook Thrift service on my machine. I used a sample code to show its working:

```
import asyncio

from fbnet.command_runner.thrift_client import AsyncioThriftClient

# Import FCR Thrift Types
from fbnet.command_runner_asyncio.CommandRunner import ttypes as fcr_ttypes

# Import FCR Service Client
from fbnet.command_runner_asyncio.CommandRunner.Command import Client as FcrClient

import getpass

# Device Information
hostname = 'my_vm'
username = 'root'
password = getpass.getpass('%s Password: ' % username)

# Destination device
device = fcr_ttypes.Device(hostname=hostname, username=username,     password=password)

async def run(cmd, device):
    async with AsyncioThriftClient(FcrClient, 'x.x.x.x',22 ) as client:
        res = await client.run(cmd, device)
        # type of res is `struct CommandResult`
        print(res.output)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run('uname -a', device))
```

However I am getting the following error:

> Frame size 1397966893 too large for THeaderProtocol Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>   File "pgm1.py", line 28, in 
>       loop.run_until_complete(run('uname -a', device))
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 467, in run_until_complete
>       return future.result()
>   File "pgm1.py", line 23, in run
>       res = await client.run(cmd, device) thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Connection closed

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Where does that strange value of `1397966893 = 0x5353482D` come from? Some uninitialized variable?

Comment: I don't know anything about thrift, but 0x5353482D is the four characters "SSH-", which happens to be the first data sent by an ssh server when something connects to it. My guess is that you're trying to start up thrift on a raw TCP socket connected to the ssh server.

Answer (score 0):

@Kenster's comment indicates the real problem here.

> 0x5353482D is the four characters "SSH-", which happens to be the first data sent by an ssh server when something connects to it

There are [some server implementations that require `TFramedProtocol` by design](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift/blob/25852037a15e4c89e1903c6a1525a3ad740a036d/thrift/lib/py/server/TAsyncioServer.py#L132). In other words, it is mandatory, the client has to use it, simply because the server expects it that way.

The insight comes quickly to one who knows that `TFramedProtocol` adds a 4 byte header carrying the frame size of the data to follow. If the client does not use `TFramedProtocol`, the server will interpret the first four databytes as the frame size - hence the error message.

### Solution

Add `TFramedProtocol` on the client side to the Thrift transport/protocol stack.

Comment: How do I add the TFramedProtocol to my code. I dont want to change anything apart from the file above. It must run independently.

Comment: I wasn't aware that [the whole example comes from Github](https://github.com/facebookincubator/FCR). Why don't you just contact the author of it and/or file an issue there?